# How can I select all nodes of a path at once in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path

I like the 'autosmooth' feature on curves (lines) in Inkscape.

Sometimes I want to smooth out a complete path.

I choose 'edit paths by nodes', click on the node I want to smooth, and then use the 'autosmooth' button.  But I have to repeat this for every node in the path.

I know I can select multiple nodes by shift+clicking them all, but that becomes tedious as well.

Is there a way to select all the nodes of a path at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Choose the node tool.
- Click at the path, so that all nodes get lightly marked
- pull a rectangle around all the nodes you like to smooth/round
- select the action

Comment: So obvious once you know it ;-)

Answer (score 7):

With the path selected by the node tool, simply typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will select all nodes.